# how to solve trying to get property of non object in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get the last inserted amount to be displayed on textbox..
Controller code:

```
    $this->db->select('amount');
    $this->db->order_by("recno", "desc");
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get('daybook');
    $data['r']=$query->result_array();
```

View code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Credit" name="amount1" id="TDAmt" class="form-control input-xs sum2" value="<?php echo $r->amount; ?>"  >
```

I am getting the below error

```
    Message: Undefined variable: r
    Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

How can i solve this..Help me to achieve this..

Comment: Did you pass your data to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result will be only one, you can use **'row_array'** instead of **'result_array'**. 
If you use **row** array you can access the value by **$r['amount']**
If it is **result** array you can access the value by **$r[0]['amount']**

Answer (score 1):

Your error message is saying `Message: Trying to get property of non-object`. You also calling `$data['r']=$query->result_array();`  So it is not an object, It is an associative array. As it is not an object rather than it is a associative array so you can not use `->` Operator. You need to access value like `$r['amount']`.

You also can value check in your template file. like this `<?php echo isset($r) ? $r['amount'] : ''; ?>`

You can also `var_dump` before printing in the template.

I think it will help you. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..still i am getting the same error and it's printing correct value in var_dump

Comment: please share your `var_dump` value. It will help other to understand your problem.

Comment: This is my var_dump value..var_dump($data['r']); array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["amount"]=> string(3) "500" } }

Comment: `<?php echo isset($r) ? $r[0]['amount'] : ''; ?>` I think it will solve your problem...

Comment: cause it is nested .. one level deeper.

Comment: okey..thanks for the reply..i solved the issue by $data['r']=$query->row_array();